# Paste every two lines in a file together as one line BASH

Tags: bash, file, awk

My colleague has given me a file, in which half of the lines are made of 8 columns of info and the other half are made of the 9th column of info. They are always next to each other, e.g.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1.1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1.2
...
a b c d e f g h
abcd
```

I know how to paste every two lines as one and print them out in Python. But I was wondering if it's possible to do that even more conveniently in BASH?

Thanks guys!

Comment: self-answering question: http://man.cx/paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `awk`

```
awk '{f=$0;getline;print f,$0}' file
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1.1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1.2
```

---

And just for the fun of it a `gnu awk`

```
awk -v RS="[0-9][.][0-9]" '{$1=$1;print $0,RT}' file
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1.1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1.2
```

Here is set the Record Separator to the value in line two.
Then the `RT` will have the actual separator stored.

Answer (score 4):

You could use sed or awk, as other answers have mentioned.  Those answers are all good.

You could also do this easily in pure shell.

```
$ while read line1; do read line2; echo "$line1 $line2"; done < input.txt
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1.1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1.2
```

Note that whitespace is not preserved.

There's another tool available on most unix-like systems called `paste`:

```
$ paste - - < input.txt
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8         1.1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1.2
```

In this case, there's a big space in the first line because `paste` separates columns using tabs, by default, and the trailing space in the first line of input.txt caused the separating tab to be offset to the next column.  You can read paste's man page for options to control this.

Comment: +1 for the clever use of `paste`; re separator used by `paste`: use `-d ' '` to separate with a space; re whitespace: specifically, _leading and trailing_ whitespace is not preserved; @chepner's approach fixes that.

Comment: Thanks -- yup, I know about `-d`, but I was hoping to encourage some extra man page reading.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can `sed`:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' file
```

or `awk`:

```
awk 'NF==1{print $0}{printf "%s ",$0}' file
```

Comment: +1 for the clever `sed` solution; the `awk` solution doesn't generalize well, as it relies on the 2nd line of each pair containing only a single word.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%2?FS:RS)}' file
```

or:

```
awk 'NR%2{printf "%s ",$0;next}7' file
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1.1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1.2"|awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%2?FS:RS)}'
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  1.1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1.2

kent$  echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1.1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1.2"|awk 'NR%2{printf "%s ",$0;next}7'     
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  1.1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1.2
```

Comment: +1 for elegance; re your use of `7` rather than `1` as a shorthand for `true`: You've previously explained that this is for your typing convenience, but would you consider _not_ doing that _on SO_? Your solutions are great, but the `7` can cause confusion (as it did for me initially).

Comment: A small variation `awk 'NF>1{printf "%s ",$0;next}1'`

Comment: @mklement0 thanks, regarding the `7`, if it was really confusing, I would try to type `1` instead of `7` from now on, but I am not sure how long time I need to get used to it. ;)

Comment: @Kent Beware! There are people in line to take that number if you decide to give it up. I just overheard someone drinking vodka martini shaken but not stirred talking about it.